# How to make the return variable hold a new value after Increment/Decrementing it in a function?

Tags: javascript

Everytime I run this function, the p1_Balance will always reset back to 10 and will not hold the new value of an increment or decrement.

```
function Balance() {
  var p1_Balance=10;
  var x= Math.floor(10*Math.random());
  if (x<5) {
    p1_Balance=p1_Balance-1;
  } else {
    p1_Balance=p1_Balance+1;
  }
  return p1_Balance;
}
```

Comment: @ruhul One can do some research, before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `p1_Balance` into the function instead of initializing it each time the function is called with: `var p1_Balance = 10;`

Answer (score 0):

There could be several solutions:
one is declaring p1_Balance as a global variable.

```
var p1_Balance=10;
function Balance(){

var x= Math.floor(10*Math.random());
if (x<5) {
  p1_Balance=p1_Balance-1;
}
else {
  p1_Balance=p1_Balance+1;
}
return p1_Balance;
}
```

another is you could pass balance as a function parameter:

```
function Balance(p1_Balance){

var x= Math.floor(10*Math.random());
if (x<5) {
  p1_Balance=p1_Balance-1;
}
else {
  p1_Balance=p1_Balance+1;
}
return p1_Balance;
}

.....

value = Balance(10);// value=something that you want to change by that function.
```

Answer (score 0):

p1_Balance should be declared outside the scope of the function (meaning not within the function itself). Otherwise, each time the function is called, the initializer that sets the value to 10 runs as well.

```
var p1_Balance=10;
function Balance(){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Javascript closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) to create a function that does what you want, as you can see below:

```js
var Balance = (function() {
  var p1_Balance = 10;
  return function() {
    var x = Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
    if (x < 5)
      return p1_Balance += 1;
    else
      return p1_Balance -= 1;
  };
})();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(Balance());
```

Alternatively, you will need to define the `p1_Balance` variable outside the function or pass it as an argument.